# Cannot download from browser inside of my VM

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, internet-explorer, download

Just as the title states, I am unable to download anything from the browser from within my VM. Forinstance trying to download a windows program called ActiveX from internet explorer inside of my VM, but as soon as the dl goes to start it says there was an error and nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Give us more details. Host OS, guest OS, error message, browser info, VM software used.

Comment: Host:Windows 8.1
Guest: Windows XP x64 pro
Basic windows xp internet explorer
VM Ware 11.1
  The website has encountered a problem and cannot display the page you are trying to view. The options provided below might help you solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing that you are using IE6 and that webpages are loading normally. Have you tried downloading using some other browser?

Comment: Trying to get firefox running as the newer IE wont allow me to dl due to it being out dated. But I cant install FF because I need SP 2, cant dl SP 2 because it always links me to install ActiveX. And I just tried getting windows xp sp2 on my pc and transferring the install exe over and running it but the error I get says that sp 2 cannot be installed because it is for a different hardware platform...

Comment: You should be able to install old Firefox (version number lower than 3.6) on XP without service pack. These are available to download from Mozilla via FTP (maybe that will work). Google "Firefox archive" and you should be able to find suitable file.

Comment: I was able to get a working FF up and running, quick question is VM ware 11.1 capable of mulitseating?

Comment: I didn't use VM ware since the ancient times so I can't help you with that.